# Neumann series expansion for the resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, functional-calculus

If $T$ is an operator on $l_2$, and $\lambda>r(T)$ (where $r(T)$ denoted the spectral radius of $T$), the resolvent $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ can be expanded as 
$$
   (\lambda I-T)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}I+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}T+\frac{1}{\lambda^3}T^2+\dots
$$

If we fix some $x\in l_2$, and denote $y:=(\lambda I-T)^{-1}x$ the above expansion implies that $y$ is in the closed span of $(T^nx)_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Is $y$ in this span even when $\lambda<r(T)$, so we do not have the Neumann series above to get that conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take $T$ to be the right shift operator on $l^2(\mathbb Z)$. It is invertible, but $T^{-1}x$ is not in the closure of the span of $(T^nx)_{n\ge0}$ for all $x\in l^2(\mathbb Z)\setminus \{0\}$ such that there is $K$ with $x_k=0$ for all $k<K$. (I.e. take $x=e_k$ to be a unit vector). I suspect that this holds for all $x\ne0$ but could not prove it.

---

If we assume that $\lambda$ belongs to the path-connected component of the resolvent set that contains $\{\mu:|\mu|>r(T)\}$ then the claim is true: 
$(\lambda I-T)x$ is in the closure of the span of $(T^nx)$ for $|\lambda|>r(T)$.
If we have $\lambda_0$ in the resolvent set then for $\lambda$ close to $\lambda_0$, $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ can be written as power series in  $(\lambda_0 I-T)^{-1}$. Then using path-wise connectedness and a covering argument, one should be able to prove the claim.

Comment: 's I don't think this answers the question. It wasn't whether the RHS converges, but whether the $(\lambda I - T) x$ is in the closed span of $(T^nx)$ for **al**l $\lambda$

Comment: @Theo I overhauled the answer completely.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great example. Do you have a reference for the statement when $\lambda$ is in the unbounded component of the resolvent set?